# Lie Derivative in Projective Hilbert Space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lie-algebras, projective-space

In considering a projective Hilbert space, $P(H)$, for linear maps (tensors) of vectors in the space, $A^{a}_{b}v_{a}=u_b$, is there a natural definition for the Lie Derivative for such linear maps? or rather, is there a natural Lie Derivative for operators on the Hilbert space of states?  Thanks.